# grails wsclient "file not found" consuming a .net web service

Tags: grails, asmx, file-not-found, ws-client

first of all, I want to apologize if my question is stupid, but I'm really new in consuming .net web service in grails.

There's a SOAP WS (wich I can't manipulate in any way) that I consume whis way:

```
def wsdlURL = "_HttpUrl_'/AspNetOracleProviderService.asmx?WSDL"
def proxy = webService.getClient(wsdlURL) <= This is the line where my project fails
```

Now, I've tested this service in a asp.Net Project with no troubles, but in Grails it generates me this error:

> Error 500: Executing action [create] of controller [pruebaplugins.PruebaWsClientController] caused exception: Unable to create JAXBContext for generated packages: "com.something.anothersomething" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index

I have defined the JAVA_HOME and javac Is there, I can acces to it in any location in a command prompt.

*At the end of this post I'll put de detailed info.*

I've only tested this service and the well-known Celsius-Farenheit example, wich works with no problems, I think it's because it only returns a String, unlike mine or any other services.

I don't know if its a lack of something, surely could be something I ignore.
Like I said, I'm very new in this kind of stuff and I'd appreciate any kind of help.

Thanks anyway.

---

---

Detailed info:
When I put

```
debug 'org.apache.cxf'
```

in log4j in Config.groovy
the output throw me this:

> 2012-01-25 16:08:13,514 [http-8080-2] INFO  spring.BusApplicationContext  - Refreshing org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext@5c3e99: startup date [Wed Jan 25 16:08:13 CLST 2012]; root of context hierarchy
>   2012-01-25 16:08:13,639 [http-8080-2] INFO  spring.BusApplicationContext
>   - No cxf.xml configuration file detected, relying on defaults.
>
> 2012-01-25 16:08:13,820 [http-8080-2] DEBUG spring.ControlledValidationXmlBeanDefinitionReader
>   - Loaded 0 bean definitions from location pattern [classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-http.xml]
>
> 2012-01-25 16:08:13,848 [http-8080-2] DEBUG spring.BusApplicationContext
>   - Bean factory for org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext@5c3e99: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@e3e8f3: defining beans [cxf,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationListener,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusWiringBeanFactoryPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.Jsr250BeanPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusExtensionPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.resource.ResourceManager,org.apache.cxf.configuration.Configurer,org.apache.cxf.binding.BindingFactoryManager,org.apache.cxf.transport.DestinationFactoryManager,org.apache.cxf.transport.ConduitInitiatorManager,org.apache.cxf.wsdl.WSDLManager,org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseManager,org.apache.cxf.workqueue.WorkQueueManager,org.apache.cxf.buslifecycle.BusLifeCycleManager,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerRegistry,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerLifeCycleManager,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientLifeCycleManager,org.apache.cxf.transports.http.QueryHandlerRegistry,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.EndpointResolverRegistry,org.apache.cxf.headers.HeaderManager,org.apache.cxf.catalog.OASISCatalogManager,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServiceContractResolverRegistry,org.apache.cxf.binding.corba.CorbaBindingFactory,org.apache.cxf.binding.corba.wsdl.WSDLExtensionRegister#0,org.apache.cxf.jaxws.context.WebServiceContextResourceResolver,org.apache.cxf.jaxws.context.WebServiceContextImpl,org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingFactory,org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapTransportFactory,org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.customEditorConfigurer,org.apache.cxf.binding.xml.XMLBindingFactory,org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.policy.AddressingAssertionBuilder,org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.policy.AddressingPolicyInterceptorProvider,org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.policy.UsingAddressingAssertionBuilder,org.apache.cxf.javascript.JavascriptQueryHandlerRegistry,org.apache.cxf.transport.local.LocalTransportFactory,org.apache.cxf.transport.http.policy.HTTPClientAssertionBuilder,org.apache.cxf.transport.http.policy.HTTPServerAssertionBuilder,org.apache.cxf.transport.http.policy.NoOpPolicyInterceptorProvider,org.apache.cxf.transport.http.ClientOnlyHTTPTransportFactory,org.apache.cxf.management.InstrumentationManager,org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPTransportFactory,org.apache.cxf.transport.jms.JMSTransportFactory,org.apache.cxf.binding.object.ObjectBindingFactory,org.apache.cxf.binding.http.HttpBindingFactory,org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSBindingFactory,org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.WSSecurityPolicyLoader,org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistry,org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyInterceptorProviderRegistry,org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.external.DomainExpressionBuilderRegistry,org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.external.EndpointReferenceDomainExpressionBuilder,org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyBuilder,org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyEngine,org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.wsdl11.Wsdl11AttachmentPolicyProvider,org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.ServiceModelPolicyProvider,org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.mtom.MTOMAssertionBuilder,org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.mtom.MTOMPolicyInterceptorProvider,org.apache.cxf.ws.rm.RMManager,org.apache.cxf.ws.rm.policy.RMPolicyInterceptorProvider,org.apache.cxf.ws.rm.RMAssertionBuilder]; root of factory hierarchy
>
> 2012-01-25 16:08:14,009 [http-8080-2] DEBUG spring.BusApplicationContext
>   - Unable to locate MessageSource with name 'messageSource': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource@cb229]
>
> 2012-01-25 16:08:14,009 [http-8080-2] DEBUG spring.BusApplicationContext
>   - Unable to locate ApplicationEventMulticaster with name 'applicationEventMulticaster': using default [org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster@184b649]
>
> 2012-01-25 16:08:16,095 [http-8080-2] DEBUG spring.BusApplicationContext
>   - Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@1e10f02]
>
> 2012-01-25 16:08:18,925 [http-8080-2] INFO  dynamic.DynamicClientFactory
>   - Created classes: com.something.anothersmth.Aplicacion, com.something.anothersmth.ArrayOfControl, com.something.anothersmth.ArrayOfModulo, com.something.anothersmth.ArrayOfPagina, com.something.anothersmth.ArrayOfRol, etc (...all the classes)
>
> javac: file not found: C:\Users\DYT01\AppData\Local\Temp\org.apache.cxf.endpoint.dynamic.DynamicClientFactory@8a3c71-1327518498999-src\com\something\anothersmth\CambiarContraseña.java
>
> Usage: javac  
>   use -help for a list of possible options
>
> 2012-01-25 16:08:20,637 [http-8080-2] ERROR dynamic.DynamicClientFactory  - Could not compile java files for ...*HttpUrl*/AspNetOracleProviderService.asmx?WSDL.